# How to start mysql database at localhost for node.js server?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I've found a bunch of tutorials which tell me how to use mysql for node.js, but since i am a newbie - i don't know how to create localhost mysql database.
Can anyone explain me how to or just send link to tutorial?

I am using this code in my node.js server:

```
app.use(
    connection(mysql,{
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : '',
        database : 'test',
        debug    : false //set true if you wanna see debug logger
    },'request')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll need to install the javascript client which connects Node to MySQL. You can do this by `npm install MySQL`.

To create a connection, use

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'test'
});
```

To connect to the DB, run `connection.connect();`

Following this, you can execute a query by

```
connection.query('SELECT now()', function(err, rows) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('The current time is: ', rows[0].solution);
});
```

For more you can visit [this](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/) and [this](http://www.codediesel.com/nodejs/querying-mysql-with-node-js/).

Comment: Where shoud i place my databese ('test')?

Comment: You'll need to set up a mysql server on your system. You can download it from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.html.

Once you do that log into your mysql instance by writing mysql -u'[your username]' -p'[your password]'. Once you do that create a new database test by using the command 'create database test'.